# How to read cplex virtual machine configuration file through Pyomo in windows?

Tags: python, windows, distributed-computing, cplex, pyomo

I am setting up cplex distributed computing over two machines (windows system) in Pyomo. How can I do that in a python script?

I have already set up the cplex distributed computing connection through tcp/ip and can do parallel computing using Cplex Interactive Optimizer as instructed here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/parallel_optim/distribMIP/09_tcp_ip.html

I don't know how to do the same thing in Pyomo API. Based on my research, pyomo's SolverFactory can only change the settings of solver parameters. What I want to do is to change the vmc settings through Pyomo API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be possible to do this through pyomo, but you can certainly do it using the CPLEX Python API directly. See the documentation for [Cplex.copy_vmconfig](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html#copy_vmconfig), [Cplex.read_copy_vmconfig](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html#read_copy_vmconfig), etc. Also, CPLEX comes with the `distmipex1.py`  and `distmipex2.py` examples (you can find these under `COS_INSTALL_DIR/cplex/examples/src/distmippython`).

Comment: Thanks! But I have a very complicated problem already modeled in pyomo. A workaround I have now is to write the pyomo problem in a lp file then do tcp/ip distributed computing through Cplex Interactive Optimizer. This is going to be a problem when more lp files are required. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: First, you should use SAV file format instead of LP file format, if possible. When you export to LP file format you can loose precision. Second, It would be easy to read the model file with the CPLEX Python API and then solve it with distributed MIP. In fact, this is exactly what the `distmipex1.py` script does. You could do all of this in Python with a data pipeline to avoid having any manual steps.

Comment: Much appreciated it! I will look into that. A quick follow up question: can I distributed computing over multiple problems using the CPLEX Pythong API? Right now I am using "multiprocessing" library on a single machine to solve multiple problems at the same time.

Comment: Sure, that should be technically possible. You'll have to be careful about how you allocate jobs to the workers. For example, CPLEX will use all of the cores on a given machine by default (up to 32), so if you want to solve two problems on the same worker machine at the same time then you'll want to set the global thread count parameter in the vmc file to avoid resource starvation (see [using multiple processes as workers on a single machine](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/parallel_optim/distribMIP/15_single_machine.html)).

Answer (score 0):

When you use Pyomo with the CPLEX Interactive Optimizer (`--solver cplex`), Pyomo saves your problem in a `.lp` file, then launches CPLEX and sends it a series of commands to read and solve the model and then save results. At one point, I needed to add a step to this to fix integer variables in a MIP model and re-solve it to get dual values for all the constraints. To do that, I patched the CPLEX script before Pyomo sent it to CPLEX. It was rough-and-ready, but it has held up pretty well. You can see that code here: https://github.com/switch-model/switch/blob/2.0.6/switch_model/solve.py#L791

You could use similar code for your purposes. For example, you could run this code sometime before you solve your model:

```py
from pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers.CPLEX import CPLEXSHELL
old_create_command_line = CPLEXSHELL.create_command_line

def new_create_command_line(*args, **kwargs):
    # call original command
    command = old_create_command_line(*args, **kwargs)
    # alter script
    if hasattr(command, 'script'):
        command.script = 'read configuration.vmc\n' + command.script
        print("changed CPLEX solve script to the following:")
        print(command.script)
    else:
        print ("Unable to patch CPLEX solver script to read configuration.vmc.")
    return command

CPLEXSHELL.create_command_line = new_create_command_line
```